# How to do a function that return all the tree's branch as string in a list

Tags: tree, scheme

[image]

For example in this case it should return ("casa" "caso "cal" "cola" "coma" "cena").

I have done this, trying to use tail's  recursion :

```
(define (palabras-tree tree)
  (palabras-tree-aux '() tree))

(define (palabras-tree-aux l tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
      (cons (symbol->string (root tree)) l)
      (cons (symbol->string(root tree))
            (fold-right append '() (map (lambda (t)
                                          (string-append (symbol->string (root t)))
                                          (palabras-tree-aux l  t)) (children tree))))))
```

But it returns this: {c a s a o l o l a m o e n a}

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Is this Lisp? If so you should probably tag it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't recognize the variant. My bad for not checking the scheme tag myself.

Comment: I haven't worked with Lisp, but I think is very similar. So that's why your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation, without tail recursion (tested with DrRacket):

```
(define (all-names tree)
  (let ((first-char (symbol->string (root tree))))
    (if (leaf? tree)
        (list first-char)
        (map (lambda (el) (string-append first-char el))
             (append-map all-names (children tree))))))
```

Comment: I have never used that append-map. I know append and map, but not that one.

Comment: `append-map` is equal to `append*` of a `map`, and the last form can be substituted by `(append* (map all-names (children tree)))`. `append*` appends together all the list of its last argument, that is, `(append* '(a) '(b) '((c) (d)))` returns `(a b c d)`.

Comment: I am used to use it like this:

`(fold-right append '() (map all-names (children tree))`

Thanks!